# How to Generate a QR Code in column 1 so tha if we scan it should show the details of the remaining columns

Tags: excel, sharepoint, qr-code, powerapps-canvas

Actually I'm trying to create an application where I have data in EXCEL file with columns of text,images, alphanumerics,dates,I need to create app using Powerapps where if scan a QR Code it show the particular details

I'm creating a student tracking data if I scan a QR code a student it should show all his details which are in Excel file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.